# JDBC MySQL reading and writing TIMESTAMP as milliseconds since Unix Epoch

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, timestamp

I have a TIMESTAMP column in a MySQL table which I am accessing through JDBC.  On the Java side, I am using JodaTime.

I would like to represent all my instants as milliseconds since the Unix epoch.  I would just use an integer field, but I want to use the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` syntax which is only supported for TIMESTAMP/DATETIME types.

JodaTime allow me to easily convert between the different representations and milliseconds since epoch, but [it's not so simple to use milliseconds since epoch with JDBC/MYSQL](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=7818).

Is there any way I can us JDBC to store milliseconds_since_epoch in a TIMESTAMP column, and retrieve TIMESTAMP columns as milliseconds_since_epoch without having to worry about the values changing due to the client or the server changing timezones.

I would prefer to not have to mess with mysql server settings or jdbc connection settings, but I would be willing to if it's the only way.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you don't want to use bigint and actually **store** the milliseconds instead of targeting date/time conversions? If it's just the fast that TIMESTAMP column updates, you can define a matching trigger. And first you rely on MySQL to update the column automatically but then again you need a way to set it... Which is it?

Comment: I am beginning to think that using a bigint +trigger is my best option, but I am still leaving this question open in case there is some nice way to do it.  If there's no method to set the field through JDBC, that would probably be okay, as I don't think I need both setting+auto updates for the same column, but it would be nice if the timestamp field could serve both purposes.

Comment: You might want to think about selection / reporting as well: Date columns offer some very nice embedded functions, while seconds/milliseconds are not very handy in terms of grouping by same weekday and stuff...

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way I can us JDBC to store milliseconds_since_epoch in a TIMESTAMP column, and retrieve TIMESTAMP columns as milliseconds_since_epoch

**For MySQL Server versions prior to 5.6.4:**

No. A TIMESTAMP column will discard fractional seconds (ref: [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fractional-seconds.html)).

If you really need to store milliseconds then you'll have to put them in a separate numeric column. However, if you can make do with time resolution of whole seconds then a TIMESTAMP column will automatically convert values to UTC when they are stored (ref: [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)).

**For MySQL Server versions 5.6.4 and later:**

Yes. See the following MySQL documentation topic for more information:

[Fractional Seconds in Time Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html)

Comment: This has evolved with MySQL 5.7 : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

Comment: Actually, MySQL 5.6.4 added the support. MySQL before 5.6.4 does not support it, but 5.6.4 or later (including all of 5.7) does support fractional seconds in time values.

Answer (score 0):

## Let your tools worry about the milliseconds

You are fighting against the type system of SQL, JDBC, and Java. Do not worry about the milliseconds. Your database, driver, and Java are already doing that for you, but finer (microseconds in MySQL, nanoseconds in Java).

> I would like to represent all my instants as milliseconds since the Unix epoch.

This is exactly what MySQL is doing for you in its `TIMESTAMP` data type, only finer - A count of microseconds since start of 1970 in UTC. To [quote the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html):

> TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.
>
> …
>
> TIMESTAMP value can include a trailing fractional seconds part in up to microseconds (6 digits) precision

Your concern about staying in UTC…

> retrieve TIMESTAMP columns as milliseconds_since_epoch without having to worry about the values changing due to the client or the server changing timezones

…is already addressed. MySQL is storing a `TIMESTAMP` in UTC, your JDBC driver should be retrieving the value in UTC, and the java.time class `Instant` stores the value in UTC. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction). **So you have UTC only, all the way through.**

Avoid the troublesome old date-time classes whenever possible. Instead use their replacement, the java.time classes. If your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) is updated for [JDBC 4.2](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) and later you can work directly with java.time types.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Current moment in UTC with resolution up to nanoseconds.
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

…and…

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

If your JDBC driver is not yet compliant, briefly use the old java.sql types but convert immediately to/from java.time. Do not perform business logic with the java.sql types.

```
myPreparedStatement.setTimestamp( … , java.sql.Timestamp.from( instant ) ) ;
```

…and…

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getTimestamp( … ).toInstant() ;
```

When you *want* to adjust out of UTC and into a time zone such as for presentation to a user, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Search Stack Overflow for many more examples.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;  // Same moment, different wall-clock time.
```

If you insist on accessing milliseconds-since-epoch, interrogate the `Instant` object. But beware of data-loss, as that instant may hold microseconds from MySQL or nanoseconds from other sources. Asking for milliseconds means truncating the finer fraction of a second.

```
long millisSinceEpoch = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

Going the other direction.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( millisSinceEpoch ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).